# Select record over date range in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table which holds Rate of resource having UserId, Effective Date(datatype Date) & End Date(datatype Date)

```
RateId UserId Rate     EffectiveDate          EndDate
============================================================================
21  169 82  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
23  78  58  2015-07-01 00:00:00.000 2015-07-14 00:00:00.000
24  88  68  2015-07-01 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
25  114 78  2015-07-01 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
26  218 56  2015-07-01 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
27  78  89  2015-07-15 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
28  174 69  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-08-14 00:00:00.000
29  174 59  2015-08-15 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
30  235 65  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-08-14 00:00:00.000
31  235 84  2015-08-15 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
32  234 49  2015-08-01 00:00:00.000 2015-08-14 00:00:00.000
33  234 59  2015-08-15 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
34  303 89  2014-10-01 00:00:00.000 2015-08-14 00:00:00.000
35  303 75  2015-08-15 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
36  481 84  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
```

I need to select rates for those user only whose rate falls only range of the current month(between Start Date & End date of month).

This is what i tried up to now.

```
DECLARE @MONTH INT
DECLARE @YEAR INT
DECLARE @STARTDATEOFMONTH DATE
DECLARE @LASTDATEOFMONTH DATE
SET @MONTH = 8 /*Current Month*/
SET @YEAR = 2015 /*Current Year*/
SET @STARTDATEOFMONTH = DATEADD(MONTH,@MONTH-1,DATEADD(YEAR,@YEAR-1900,0)) /*FIRST*/
SET @LASTDATEOFMONTH = DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,@MONTH,DATEADD(YEAR,@YEAR-1900,0))) /*LAST*/

SELECT * FROM TRNS_RATE_DETAILS
  WHERE  @STARTDATEOFMONTH >= EFFECTIVEDATE 
  AND @LASTDATEOFMONTH <= ENDDATE
```

I am calculating Start Date and End Date of every month (say in the above query i have passed Current month=8 & year=2015)

Query output is

```
RateId  UserId  Rate       EffectiveDate          EndDate
============================================================================
21  169 82  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
24  88  68  2015-07-01 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
25  114 78  2015-07-01 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
26  218 56  2015-07-01 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
27  78  89  2015-07-15 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
36  481 84  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2025-12-30 00:00:00.000
```

As You can see i can get only those record which comes before Start Date of current Month & after Last date of current month.

I need to get those records whose Effective Date & End Date falls between Start Date & End Date of every months.

Say, I have Rate = 45 for Resource(UserId) for Date between 1-Jan-2015(Effective Date) to 14th Aug(End Date) and another Rate = 75 for Date between 15-Aug-2015(Effective Date) to 30th Dec 2025(End Date)

So i actually want both Rates(45 & 75) for the same resource for the Month of August, 2015?

Please help me out!

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the last day of the current month? Think about it differently - you want >= the first day of the current month, and < the first day of the next month. Not a query that solves your question but definitely a simpler way to calculate your range.

Comment: Do you want current month (i.e. August) or 30 day period?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Say for one user i have only one rate from 1st Jan, 15 to 1 Dec, 15, but for another user i have two rates one is from 1 jan, 15 to 14th Aug, 15 and second is from 15th Aug,15 to 31st Dec, 15

Can ur suggestion works  in this case?

Comment: @Samcd August (each month) not a 30 day period only rate falls betwen start and end date of every month

Comment: Sorry, don't know, haven't tried to grok your actual question. Was just cautioning you [against using BETWEEN (>= and <=) for date range queries](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use the current month, you can use `DATEPART` and `GETDATE`:

```
SELECT * FROM TRNS_RATE_DETAILS
  WHERE  
  (
   (DATEPART(month,EFFECTIVEDATE) <= DATEPART(month,GETDATE())
   AND DATEPART(year,EFFECTIVEDATE) = DATEPART(year,GETDATE()))
   OR
   DATEPART(year,EFFECTIVEDATE) < DATEPART(year,GETDATE())
   )
  AND 
  (
   (DATEPART(month,ENDDATE) >= DATEPART(month,GETDATE())
   AND DATEPART(year,ENDDATE) = DATEPART(year,GETDATE()))
   OR
   DATEPART(year,ENDDATE) > DATEPART(year,GETDATE())
  )
```

Comment: I ran ur query an i m getting only those record which effective date is in August only what about those whose effective Date is  Jan,15 and End Date is Dec, 15, Dont this also fall for August also?

Answer (score 0):

You want EFFECTIVEDATE between startdate and lastdate... but you are actually ask the db for record having startdate greater than effective date.... which is the opposite that you want.

try:

```
SELECT * FROM TRNS_RATE_DETAILS
  WHERE EFFECTIVEDATE >= @STARTDATEOFMONTH 
AND ENDDATE <=@LASTDATEOFMONTH
```

Btw, way don't you just check for the month using the extract function?

Comment: Because some of the months have two different values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM    TRNS_RATE_DETAILS
WHERE   (MONTH(EFFECTIVEDATE)   =   @MONTH  AND YEAR(EFFECTIVEDATE) =   @YEAR)
OR      (MONTH(ENDDATE)         =   @MONTH  AND YEAR(ENDDATE)       =   @YEAR)
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response, but your query gives only those record whose Effective date and End date falls in current month, but i am also want those records whose Effective Date is 1st Jan 2015 and End date is 30th Dec 2025(August,2015 also falls between these date range)

Comment: Hi vinay,  just try this,SELECT * 
FROM    TRNS_RATE_DETAILS
WHERE   (YEAR(EFFECTIVEDATE) =   @YEAR)
OR      (YEAR(ENDDATE)       =   @YEAR)

Comment: if you want both , use this.................. SELECT * 
FROM    TRNS_RATE_DETAILS
WHERE   (YEAR(EFFECTIVEDATE) =   @YEAR)
AND     (YEAR(ENDDATE)       =   @YEAR)

Comment: This will help you to order your record 

ORDER BY EFFECTIVEDATE,ENDDATE